# got error in java.lang.NullPointerExceptions

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

i had a problem of my program it is process completed but it has runtime exception the java.lang.NullPointerException. Anyone can help me ? this is my code so far .

```
  import javax.swing.*;
import java.lang.Character;
import java.io.*;
public class CoproHW
{
    public static String c;
    public static int NOc;
    public static String vince;
    public static void main(String args [])throws IOException
    {

        String vince = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Your File path :");
         c = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a character");

        briefer();
    }
    public static void briefer()
    {

        for(int v = 1; v<c.length(); v++)
        {
            char x = c.charAt(v);
            if(Character.isSpaceChar(x))
            {
                NOc++;
            }


            char z = c.charAt(v);
            if(Character.isLetter(z))
            {
                NOc++;
            }
        }

        panty();
    }
    public static void panty()
    {
        File file = new File(vince);

        if(!file.exists())
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong file path !");
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Number of Characters in "+ c +" is "+ NOc);

            try
            {
                RandomAccessFile gui = new RandomAccessFile(file," ");

                gui.writeBytes("The number of Characters in "+ c + " is " +NOc);
                gui.close();
            }

            catch(IOException m)
            {
                System.out.print(m.getMessage());
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: NOc in an int here, so that cannot be the source of the exception. Please post the stacktrace. I think your intent is to do 
File file = new File(c);
rather than
File file = new File(vince);

Answer (score 2):

Because you didn't assign value to your global `vince` variable. Instead, you assigned the expected value to a local variable:

```
String vince = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Your File path :");
```

Modify the code to:

```
vince = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Your File path :");
```

And then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `String` at the main method.

`vince = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Your File path :");`

It is a global variable you have been declared.

Comment: I'm just curious, did this add anything that wasn't already in the answer that was provided and has upvotes?

Comment: Ya, i realize this thing after i post my answer. Dont know there is another answer because when i read this post, there is no answer posted.